# Identify a certain char in a file and hide it from execution

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to java and I'M trying to do a kind of Who wants to be millionaire game. I'm doing it with 10 levels.

I have 1 folder with 5 txt files for level (1 question in each txt file). So if you repeat the game 1 or 2 times you probably won't get the same question again. The text files have the same structure like this.

```
What is the minimum of players in a footbal game?
0 1)8
0 2)10
0 3)9
1 4)7
```

The boolean before the answear options points the correct answear but when i read the file. I want to read the file and identify the correct answear(but not print it) to tell if the option the player choose is right or not.

How can I do it? Is there another way to the same? Thanks for helping :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    
    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
    int option;
    boolean menu;
    double[] balance = new double[0];
 
    //::::::::::::::::::::MENU:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<Who wants to be millionaire?>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    
    System.out.println("whats your name?"); 
    String name = input.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("Welcome"+ name);
    
    menu = true;
    while(menu==true){
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<< 1 - Play >>>>>>>>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<<< 2 - Last Score >>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<< 3 - Best 10 scores >>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<< 4 - Exit >>>>>>>>>>");
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
     
    System.out.println("choose your option: ");
    opcao=input.nextInt();  

    //:::::::::::::::::::: 1 - Play :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    switch(option){
        case 1:
        //random char to create the file name
        Random r = new Random();
        char c = (char)(r.nextInt(5) + 'a');
        String LetterFile=String.valueOf(c);  
        System.out.println(letterFile); 
        String nameFile = letterFile + ".txt";

        
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameFile));
        String line;
        while((line = read.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        ler.close();
        
        System.out.println("Whats the answear?: ");
        String answear1 = input.nextInt();  
        System.out.println("Escolheu a resposta: "+answear1 );

        break;
        
  //:::::::::::::::::::: 4 - EXIT :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::      
        case 4:

                System.out.println("THANKS FOR PLAYINGr!");
                System.exit(0);
        
    }//while
    } //switch case
}//main
```

}

[image: Structure of questions file - 5 files for each folder named a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt, e.txt]

Comment: Actually, you would do yourself a favour if you used some structured way to save your data. For example XML or JSON. It's reasonably easy to read and write "by hand" and _way_ easier to serialize / deserialize.

Comment: Hiya mate. Since you're new to this, I want to make a few suggestions regarding your approach. First, unless you have a ridiculous amount of questions then there's no need to bring files into the mix. Would be easier to just store them as a collection of objects with the question, possible answers, and actual answer stored as variables. Second, if you do decide to use files you may want to look into some data formatting libraries to make it easier to work with. For example, one I suggest is [JSON](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm). Best of luck!

Comment: When the program reads and print the question file it prints the boolean aswell

Comment: Yes but if it'd be JSON you'd not just print the raw file contents but selectively only the object properties with the questions and not the correct answers.

Comment: For example: `[{"question": "What is the minimum of players in a football game?", "answers": ["8", "10", "9", "7"], "correctAnswer": 3}]` (Note: I wrote 3 and not 4 because array indices are zero-based and I was referring to the position in the array, not the display value of it.)

Comment: Right now, you are printing the whole line. It's just a string. Java doesn't know automagically, you actually do not want to print all of it. Also, you have Question-Lines and Answer-Lines ... see where this is going?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've created the json file but when I do imports it tells me that "package.nio.org does not exist".
I already java-json.jar to the project libraries but i guess i'm doing it wrong. Could someone help me out!?
Using netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Use below JSON structure. Each file will have a json. You pick first file, read the json and populate it in your java objects (You can use a jackson library for that which will automatically do that for you, you just need to create POJO structure to map).

So

**When you need only options to display:** Use **options array object** from json populate java objects.

**When you need to display answer also:** you pick from **answer** key from java object populate from json

JSON :

```
{
  "GameName": "millionaire game",
  "level": 1,
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "What is the minimum of players in a footbal game?",
      "options": [
        8,
        10,
        9,
        7
      ],
      "answer": "7"
    },
    {
      "question": "Who scored maximum goal footbal game?",
      "options": [
        "Jhon",
        "Pitty",
        "Richard",
        "Mike"
      ],
      "answer": "Mike"
    },
    {
      "question": "What is the maximum of players in a footbal game?",
      "options": [
        8,
        10,
        9,
        7
      ],
      "answer": "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Use JSON always to perform such task. Json is easier to maintain and manage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've created the json file but when I do imports it tells me that "package.nio.org does not exist". I already java-json.jar to the project libraries but i guess i'm doing it wrong.
Using netbeans

Comment: Which jdk version are you using?

Comment: It seems to be Jdk verision issue. Please use jdk 7 or higher